# User input name JavaScript output is equal to variable attached to each letter in the name

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, input, output

This is my very first JavaScript project. What I am trying to do is when user enters there name for example  "Blake" It will output "Bravo Lima Alpha Kilo  Echo". So whatever user inputs it outputs whatever each letter variable is equal to.I added a picture to better explain what I am talking about. I also understand how when someone enters there name in a form it outputs there name. But I am not sure how you can output a variable that is equal to each letter in there name.

[image]

```js
var A = "Alpha";
var B = "Bravo";
var C = "Charlie";
var D = "Delta";
var E = "Echo";
var F = "Foxtrot";
var G = "Golf";
var H = "Hotel";
var I = "India";
var J = "Juliett";
var K = "Kilo";
var L = "Lima";
var M = "Mike";
var N = "November";
var O = "Oscar";
var P = "Papa";
var Q = "Quebec";
var R = "Romeo";
var S = "Sierra";
var T = "Tanga";
var U = "Uniform";
var V = "Victor";
var W = "Whiskey";
var X = "X-ray";
var Y = "Yankee";
var Z = "Zulu"; 



document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
A + "<br>" + B + "<br>" + C;
```

```html
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple code without changing your code

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<button id="btn">submit</button>
  <div id="output">
```

javascript:

```
var A = "Alpha";
      var B = "Bravo";
      var C = "Charlie";
      var D = "Delta";
      var E = "Echo";
      var F = "Foxtrot";
      var G = "Golf";
      var H = "Hotel";
      var I = "India";
      var J = "Juliett";
      var K = "Kilo";
      var L = "Lima";
      var M = "Mike";
      var N = "November";
      var O = "Oscar";
      var P = "Papa";
      var Q = "Quebec";
      var R = "Romeo";
      var S = "Sierra";
      var T = "Tanga";
      var U = "Uniform";
      var V = "Victor";
      var W = "Whiskey";
      var X = "X-ray";
      var Y = "Yankee";
      var Z = "Zulu"; 
      var obj = {
        a: A,
        b: B,
        c: C,
        d: D,
        e: E,
        f: F,
        g: G,
        h: H,
        i: I,
        j: J,
        k: K,
        l: L,
        m: M,
        n: N,
        o: O,
        p: P,
        q: Q,
        r: R,
        s: S,
        t: T,
        u: U,
        v: V,
        w: W,
        x: X,
        y: Y,
        z: Z
      }
      var ele1 = document.getElementById("test");
      var ele2 = document.getElementById("output");
      var ele3 = document.getElementById("btn");
      var val="";
      ele3.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        var arr = ele1.value.split('');
        for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
          val += obj[arr[index]] + ' ';
        }
        ele2.innerHTML = val;
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of [string.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Since you said you are new to JS I would also direct to you check out [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which I used as the `.map()` callback.

```js
var A = "Alpha";
var B = "Bravo";
var C = "Charlie";
var D = "Delta";
var E = "Echo";
var F = "Foxtrot";
var G = "Golf";
var H = "Hotel";
var I = "India";
var J = "Juliett";
var K = "Kilo";
var L = "Lima";
var M = "Mike";
var N = "November";
var O = "Oscar";
var P = "Papa";
var Q = "Quebec";
var R = "Romeo";
var S = "Sierra";
var T = "Tanga";
var U = "Uniform";
var V = "Victor";
var W = "Whiskey";
var X = "X-ray";
var Y = "Yankee";
var Z = "Zulu"; 




function spellWord(word){
  const uppercaseWord = word.toUpperCase() // in case they type lowercase letters
  const array = uppercaseWord.split('')
  const newArray = array.map(letter => window[letter])
  return newArray.join(' ')
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = spellWord("testing")
```

```html
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Comment: I will have to figure out how I can attach this code with to a form lol...But I think you may have got at least that part of it.  Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer to include a step which converts it to uppercase first, since you are accepting input from users

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through the `input` and set the value in the div. Let suppose, `input` is `id` of your `input` where you are entring the name.

HTML:

```
<input type="input" />
<div id="test">

</div>
```

JS

```
var data = {
 A: "Alpha",
 B: "Bravo",
 C: "Charlie",
 D: "Delta",
 E: "Echo",
 F: "Foxtrot",
 G: "Golf",
 H: "Hotel";,
 I: "India",
 J: "Juliett",
 K: "Kilo",
 L: "Lima",
 M: "Mike",
 N: "November",
 O: "Oscar",
 P: "Papa",
 Q: "Quebec",
 R: "Romeo",
 S: "Sierra",
 T: "Tanga",
 U: "Uniform",
 V: "Victor",
 W: "Whiskey",
 X: "X-ray",
 Y: "Yankee",
 Z: "Zulu"
}

document.getElelementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
    const input = this.value;
    let name = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
       name = `${name} ${data[input[i].toUpperCase()]}`;
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = name;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here the catch would be how should we able to get the variable value after splitting the work entered in the input.. Use eval('Z') which would evaluate that as a JS code , in this case a variable     
<code>
    var name = "Blake";
    var A = "Alpha";
    var B = "Bravo";
    var C = "Charlie";
    var D = "Delta";
    var E = "Echo";
    var F = "Foxtrot";
    var G = "Golf";
    var H = "Hotel";
    var I = "India";
    var J = "Juliett";
    var K = "Kilo";
    var L = "Lima";
    var M = "Mike";
    var N = "November";
    var O = "Oscar";
    var P = "Papa";
    var Q = "Quebec";
    var R = "Romeo";
    var S = "Sierra";
    var T = "Tanga";
    var U = "Uniform";
    var V = "Victor";
    var W = "Whiskey";
    var X = "X-ray";
    var Y = "Yankee";
    var Z = "Zulu"; 
    var nameArr = name.split("");
    var output="";
    for(var xx=0;xx<nameArr.length;xx++){
    console.log(nameArr[xx]);
    output+=eval(nameArr[xx].toUpperCase())+" ";
    }
    console.log(output); // Assign this value to a ID using innerHTML function
    </code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having each code as a new variable, you could for example use an array (even better would be a map) and then check for each letter of the name typed check if the array has any word that starts with that letter, something like the following:

```js
let codes = ["Alpha","Bravo","Charlie","Delta","Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","India","Juliett","Kilo","Lima","Mike","November","Oscar","Papa","Quebec","Romeo","Sierra","Tanga","Uniform","Victor","Whiskey","X-ray","Yankee","Zulu"];

input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  let code = [];
  let name = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < codes.length; j++) {
      if (name[i] === codes[j][0]) {
        code.push(codes[j]);
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = code.join(" ");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting I just learned about variables and I just had thought that you can set variables  to equal whatever you set them to.. So i then thought you could implement this into a form.

Comment: You can set them to anything, but in your case you are better served with a data structure such as a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which holds key-value pairs. So like, "A" => "Alpha".